# Crash in drawRect - EXEC BAD ACCESS

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, drawrect

My app crash in a custom `UIView` drawRect.
Crash only occurs in low-memory situation.  (After I run some games or apps, turning my app from background to foreground)
Before crash, it triggered several times drawRect, one of them, crash...

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
        NSLog(@"  ## it is in drawRect");
    //NSLog(@"timecardImage: %@ ",[timecardImage description]);
    [timecardImage drawAtPoint:(CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f))];
}
```

Crash TB:

```
#0  0x31db6c9a in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x000051c8 in -[Timecard drawRect:] (self=<value temporarily unavailable, due to optimizations>, _cmd=<value temporarily unavailable, due to optimizations>, rect={origin = {x = 0, y = 0}, size = {width = 75, height = 108}}) at /xcode_prj/TimesheetKeeper/Classes/Timecard.m:72
#2  0x34caba04 in -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] ()
#3  0x37221fac in -[CALayer drawInContext:] ()
#4  0x37221d2a in backing_callback ()
#5  0x3722177c in CABackingStoreUpdate ()
#6  0x3722117e in -[CALayer _display] ()
#7  0x37220e8c in -[CALayer display] ()
#8  0x3721570c in CALayerDisplayIfNeeded ()
#9  0x372151cc in CA::Context::commit_transaction ()
#10 0x37214fd6 in CA::Transaction::commit ()
#11 0x37213906 in CA::Transaction::pop ()
#12 0x37213884 in +[CATransaction commit] ()
#13 0x34df7bd2 in _UIWindowUpdateVisibleContextOrder ()
#14 0x34df7c66 in +[UIWindow _prepareWindowsForAppResume] ()
#15 0x34df03e4 in -[UIApplication _handleApplicationResumeEvent:] ()
...
```

Below is how I setup the UIView - self.timecard:

```
-(void)setupTimecard{
    if (!self.timecard) {       
    self.timecard = [[Timecard alloc] init];
    [self.timecard retain];
    }

    timecard.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x,10.0f);
    [self.view insertSubview:timecard atIndex:2];
    }
```

And,I comment the viewController's didReceiveMemoryWarning .
In viewDidUnload, I even do nothing on "timecard"
just release it in Dealloc.

This issue cost me several days and I still have no idea.
Any ideas you guys provide, I will try.
Thank you for your help.

---

## It's Done! ##

```
-(id)init {

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"timecard3.png"] ;
timecardImage = image;
    [timecardImage retain];    // #1 this is the key.

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    self = [self initWithFrame:frame];
return self;
}
```

In drawRect, timecardImage is the receiver of drawAtPoint, which is just a pointer to an autorelease image.
In memory warning issue, autolease image got released. And so did my timecardImage.
After i add #1 line, just a retain, 
EXC BAD ACCESS never happens.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probable that `timeCardImage` is being deallocated. If you are `retain`ing it (which you should be doing), you should follow a `release` with `nil`ing `timeCardImage`. This is assuming that you are `release`ing the values in low memory situation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick respond.-(void)setupTimecard{
 
 if (!self.timecard) {  
  self.timecard = [[Timecard alloc] init];
  [self.timecard retain];
 }
 
 timecard.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x,10.0f);
 [self.view insertSubview:timecard atIndex:2];
}  //  -- I do this when I setup the timeCard. However,it still crash. Do you mean that I should release it just after i retain it?

Comment: The code `self.timecard = [[Timecard alloc] init]; [self.timecard retain];` probably results in a triply-retained object. If your `@property` is `(retain)`, then the assignment retains it once. The `+alloc` call returns a +1 retain count, and then you're calling `-retain`. You only need a total of a +1 retain count to keep the object around. In short, your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @skingtree I don't think there are issues with `timecard` being deallocated but please check @jtbandes' comment about it. I was talking about `timecardImage` that you are using to draw. How are managing it (memory-wise)?

Comment: @jtbandes , thanks guys. Actually, the additional "[self.timecard retain]" makes me clear that the BAD ACCESS is not because of a "release" somewhere. "timecard" is a custom UIView presented manually. It looks like ios deallocated my "timecard" when it is lack of memory. I get an idea that maybe i need recreate it in somewhere such as viewDidLoad. I will post the result if I fix it. Thank you again.